# IPython installation (Mac OS X 10.9.4) error requires pyzmq

Tags: macos, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have successfully installed IPython and its dependencies, it works in command line perfectly, but it doesn't launch as "ipython notebook" in browser. The error it gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 5, in <module>
start_ipython()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 120, in start_ipython
return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 563, in launch_instance
app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 321, in initialize
super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 381, in initialize
self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 316, in parse_command_line
return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 475, in parse_command_line
return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 406, in initialize_subcommand
subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 39, in <module>
check_for_zmq('2.1.11', 'IPython.html')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/zmqrelated.py", line 37, in check_for_zmq
raise ImportError("%s requires pyzmq >= %s"%(required_by, minimum_version))
ImportError: IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 2.1.11
```

I have tried upgrading the packages. I also read that the problem is probably that IPython is installed in a different environment from its dependencies or a path is broken. Since I'm totally new to Mac, I have no idea how to correct that. Any help or any alternative solution on how to make the IPython Notebook work would be much appreciated!

Comment: what version of ipython do you have ? did you install pyzmq ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
easy_install --upgrade IPython 
easy_install --upgrade pyzmq
```

Comment: This didn't work to solve the original problem but I have now installed the Canopy software package (by Enthought), which had integrated IPython and now the notebook option works as well. But thanks for your suggestions!:)

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching and troubleshooting, I installed ipython notebook on Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10).

To avoid any permission related errors, download and install [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) with your python first.
Then continue as follows

```
$ virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)[user@host ]$ pip install ipython[all]

Successfully installed ... 

(venv)[user@host ]$ ipython notebook
```

would bring up the notebook with all the modules installed. When you're done with your environment, you can easily $deactivate it.

Comment: You could also install all required modules individually, but why bother when pip does all of that for you, in one line command.